Aligning Network Area in OMNeT++ with SUMO Road Network
I am working on a simulation involving a vehicular 5G network using Simu5G and SUMO in OMNeT++. I have set the network area size to 100x200 using the playgroundX and playgroundY properties, and I have created a SUMO road network of the same size. However, when running the simulation, the road network appears displaced, located below the network area.
I have reviewed the documentation but couldn't find a method to adjust the road network's position within the OMNeT++ simulation. Is there a way to control the alignment of the road network to match the network area in OMNeT++?
